# Commons CLI empty Options in CommandLine

Tags: java, command-line, apache-commons-cli

I don't understand how to apply `Options` to `DefaultParser` in Commons CLI.

When `CommandLine` object is created, assigned `Options` is always empty.

Bellow block of code is how i interpreted Commons CLI docs:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Options options = new Options();

    options.addOption("c", false, "why are you hidding from me");

    CommandLineParser parser = new  DefaultParser();

    System.out.println(args[0]); // this prints -c

    try {

        CommandLine line = parser.parse(options, args);

        System.out.println(line.getArgs()[0]); // prints -c

        Option[] o = line.getOptions(); // this is empty for some reason

        System.out.println(o.length); // prints 0

        if (line.hasOption("c")) { // false

            System.out.println(" flag c found");
        }
    }

    catch(ParseException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How come that `line.getOptions()` is empty,  and how to apply the options properly ?

Comment: What is the command line you're passing to your program?

Comment: -c. I basically opened eclipse's run configuration and passed -c to argument list. Still i don't think the issue is there because line.getArgs() is not empty.

Comment: At first look, I can't see anything wrong in what you've done. Which version of commons-cli are you using?

Comment: @dosyfier thank you for reply, version is commons-cli-1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce your issue but everything was OK for me.
I created a simple maven project with only the `commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3.1` dependency and a `Test` main class with the exact same method you provided in your question.

When I compile and run the main method from the Windows command line, e.g. with:

```
java -cp .;[path_to_commons_cli_jar]/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar Test -c
```

then it gave me the expected output:

- `args` is made of the single `"-c"` value;
- `line.getArgs()` returns an empty array;
- `line.getOptions()` returns an single entry array consisting of the expected `Option` object.

Maybe there are some remaining spaces that aren't stripped in the command line you use when you launch your program within eclipse? Otherwise, your code should work fine...